# How to set Return-Path header of postfix bounced messages

Tags: linux, windows, postfix, exchange, return-path

i have an debian6 with postfix and dovecot. A customer has an Exchange wich connects with an POP3 Connector onto some mailboxes. The postfix relays messages for the exchange server. Bounced messages come back into dovecot mailbox with an Return-Path header of MAILER-DAEMON. The exchange refuses to pull the mails with that header for some reason.

So the question is, how to either change the Return-Path header, or make the Windows Small Business Server to take them anyway.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: The [`empty_address_recipient`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#empty_address_recipient) directive may be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was `null_sender=` in master.cnf where the maildrop is called, this will leave an Return-Path: <> but your tip pointed me into the right direction, thanks

> maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
>   flags=DRhu user=vmail null_sender= argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d
>   ${recipient}